# Does a bandsaw up 18 inches tall or smaller exist?

Tags: power-tools, band-saw

I have a really, really small work space and I would like a bandsaw and I'm looking for something as small as possible. Even the [Proxxon MBS 240](https://www.proxxon.com/en/micromot/27172.php) is a bit too large for my space.

Do I even have a chance of finding a bandsaw that would not be taller than 18 inches (450 mm)? Or maybe it isn't even produced by anyone?

Comment: Sorry Andrei, specific shopping Questions are off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close, but at the size you're talking about you're not going to get much cut capacity or power.  You might be better off looking at a scroll saw or even a good coping saw or fret saw.

Comment: Reword your question to ask something like, "What sort of power saw can fit within this space (e.g. 15" x 30" x 18"h)

Comment: @AstPace, wouldn't that simply amount to an attempt to take an end run around that rule? While I'm all for helping with any reasonable query, if necessary using the Comments, in the Q&As it's the spirit of the rules we should honour, not just their letter.

Comment: @Graphus  wouldn't your comment be more appropriate as a question in Woodworking meta? :)

Comment: @AstPace, nah. The spirit of the rules being adhered to and not just following the letter of them is one of the guiding principles on SE, no? Do correct me if I'm wrong. I know we're not even remotely busy enough that we have to be anal about the rules but consistency is definitely important both internally and across SE sites.

Comment: @graphus, comments are not the place to carry on a discussion of topics that pertain to how SE sites might operate. I think that's  why Meta sites exist. Simply ask your question there and we can have a little discussion that doesn't detract from the information that OP seeks.

Comment: The question here isn't *what should I buy?* or *which one should I pick?*, but rather *is this thing produced commercially by anyone?* As such, it doesn't seem like a shopping question to me.

Comment: @Graphus: I carefully read the tour (https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/tour) and the rest of the pages but did not find this restriction. That is why I asked in the first place. Having found out about this restriction now, I will obey it in the future. As for the current question, the moderator(s) will decide.

Comment: I have commented on @Caleb's answer but I am not sure I should promote that piece of information as a 'later edit' part in the question body.

Comment: I have watched several videos on youtube on how to build your own bandsaw and of course, I could just do that but the effort, time and lack of quality of the end result tend to push me to commercially available products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I even have a chance of finding a bandsaw that would not be taller than 18 inches (450 mm)?

In the history of the world, it's very likely that *someone* produced a very small bandsaw at some point, and if so, one will turn up sooner or later on Ebay. If you're really looking for something like that, look for a three-wheeled bandsaw. Two-wheeled bandsaws are much more common, and in that setup the hight of the saw is basically the distance between the wheel axles plus the diameter of one of the wheels, plus a little more for the enclosure, so the height of the saw is directly related to the saw's cutting capacity. A three-wheeled model uses smaller wheels with the third wheel set off to the side to increase the width of the band's path and provide a deeper throat while limiting the height of the saw. The downside of this design is that smaller wheels mean that the blade bends more, which can stress the blade and lead to breaks.

I wonder if this isn't an XY problem, i.e. one where you're asking about the solution you expect rather than the problem you actually have. What capability does a tiny bandsaw offer that you couldn't get from, say, a scroll saw, a portable jigsaw, or a [Rockwell Bladerunner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00L47FZ8A) (basically an inverted, stationary jigsaw)? A scroll saw, for example, gives you much greater throat capacity than a small bandsaw would, and a handheld jigsaw can handle anything you can reach to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and extensive reach! I own a small scroll saw (Proxxon DS 230) and a jigsaw (Makita) plus a jig from Wolfcraft that can transform the jigsaw into something similar to the bladerunner (https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Wolfcraft-Jigsaw-Table-Precision-Jigsaw-Shape-Cutting-Work-with-2-Steel-Clamps-/322875125093). However a (commercially available, as I first wrote in the question before it was edited) bandsaw could allow me to tilt the table at a precise angle or resaw medium/large stock both of which neither the scrollsaw nor the jigsaw could easily and precise do.

Comment: Excellent point in the second paragraph Caleb, and extra +1 for that if I could.

Comment: @AndreiRînea, if space is at a real premium the ideal solution is to get into hand tools. I realise this approach might not appeal to you personally but it's *always* the option that will allow the most varied work to be done with the most limited number of tools — multiple pieces of furniture, the fittings for an entire house etc. were produced by men whose entire toolkit could fit into one chest.

Comment: I am already doing this, I returned my power miter saw and got a manual miter saw instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Milwaukee tools makes a very tiny bandsaw designed to be held in one hand. It is about 12 inches tall and built for commercial use, to replace hacksaws. The cut capacity is quite small and you will need to make a stand to hold it upright for stationary use.

Milwaukee 2429-20 M12

Answer (score 0):

Although not a large production item, this [bandsaw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTn95Ik95KM) is a small DIY which many can build.